# SwiftCharts cutting off points (clips bounds)

Tags: swiftcharts

I am tweaking the [Areas Example](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/AreasExample.swift) project from SwiftCharts and I am running into the issue where the point indicators are getting cut off like so:

[image]

In the github issues a found [this](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/issues/258) and [this other](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/issues/244) issue where the solutions were to set `chartSettings.clipInnerFrame = false`

However, when I do this the the area color awkward shape also becomes visible like so:

[image]

How can I get the whole shape of the points but all the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass to the `ChartPointsViewsLayer` with the points `clipViews: false` (see [example](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/RangedAxisExample.swift#L165)). `ChartSettings.clipInnerFrame` has to be true (i.e. the default). This way only the layer with the points is clipped.

Finally, if you want to clip the unclipped points layer (to limit the area outside of the chart where they are displayed), you can do it passing a custom rectangle, like [here](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/RangedAxisExample.swift#L175) (this setting is admittedly not very intuitive).

Comment: This almost works however now the points layer is now behind the line graph. Like so https://imgur.com/a/e5iOL

Comment: @boidkan I think this is a (probably easy to fix) bug - this functionality is relatively new and has not been tested well. I'll give it a look later today.

Comment: @boidkan Should be fixed now - please update master and try again!